# Equivalent condition for eigenvalue-eigenvector equation

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, inner-products

Am reading about kernel PCA. The set-up is a set of centered observations $\big\{x_k: k = 1,..., M\big\} \subset \mathbb{R}^N$ and we want to diagonalize the covariance matrix :

$$C = \frac{1}{M} \sum_{j=1}^M x_j x_j' $$

The text am following reads :

To do this, one has to solve the eigenvalue equation $$\lambda v = Cv$$
for eigenvalues $λ ≥ 0$ and $v ∈ \mathbb{R}^N\setminus{0}$. Since $Cv = \frac{1}{M} \sum_{j=1}^M \langle x_j, v \rangle x_j $, all solutions $v$ with $λ \neq 0$ must lie in the span of $x_1,..., x_M$. In that case the previous equation  is equivalent to

$$λ\langle x_k, v\rangle = \langle x_k, Cv \rangle $$for all $k = 1,..., M$.

**Question:** Why is this last set of equations equivalent to the eigenvalue equation?

Clearly $\lambda v = Cv$ implies $$λ\langle x_k, v\rangle = \langle x_k, Cv \rangle $$for all $k = 1,..., M$ but how can I show the converse?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume that the vectors $x_1, \dots, x_M$ are linearly independent. Given that $\lambda \langle x_k, v \rangle = \langle x_k, Cv \rangle$ for all integers $1 \leq k \leq M,$ we have that $\langle x_k, \lambda v \rangle = \langle x_k, Cv \rangle,$ from which it follows that $\langle x_k, Cv - \lambda v \rangle = 0$ for all integers $1 \leq k \leq M.$ (Both equalities here hold because our inner product is taken over $\mathbb R.$)

Considering that the inner product $\langle \cdot, Cv - \lambda v \rangle$ is a linear functional, it follows that $\langle \cdot, Cv - \lambda v \rangle$ is uniquely determined by the values that it takes on a basis. Consequently, if we restrict $\langle \cdot, Cv - \lambda v \rangle$ to $\operatorname{span}_{\mathbb R}\{x_1, \dots, x_M \},$ then in view of the fact that $\langle x_k, Cv - \lambda v \rangle = 0$ for all integers $1 \leq k \leq M,$ it follows that $\langle \cdot, Cv - \lambda v \rangle$ is the zero functional on $\operatorname{span}_{\mathbb R}\{x_1, \dots, x_M \}$ so that $\langle Cv - \lambda v, Cv - \lambda v \rangle = 0.$ But then, considering that the inner product is positive-definite, we must have that $Cv = \lambda v,$ as desired.

Comment: Great! But what if the vectors are not necessarily independent? The text am reading dosen’t seem to make this assumption.

Comment: And how do you know that $Cv$ is in the span?

Comment: If the vectors $x_1, \dots, x_M$ are not linearly independent, then $W = \operatorname{span}_{\mathbb R} \{x_1, \dots, x_M\}$ can be generated by some linearly independent vectors $x_{i_1}, \dots, x_{i_\ell}.$ Use the same argument applied to these vectors.

Comment: $Cv$ is the span of these vectors because $Cv = \frac 1 M \sum_{j = 1}^M \langle x_j, v \rangle x_j,$ right?

Comment: Actually never mind the second question only the first!

Comment: You mean I can throw out some vectors until I obtain a basis right?

Comment: Correct. Exactly.

Comment: Perfect thank you so much!